# SCSS error on nesting referencing parent selector (&)

Tags: compiler-errors, sass

Why I can't use that code from LESS in SCSS:

```
.button, .input, .textarea {
  // some staff

  &_red {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

?

I need this CSS in output:

```
.button_red,
.input_red,
.textarea_red {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Prepros on compiling shows that error:

> Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "  &": expected "{", was "_red {"
>   "_red" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector. on
>   line 4 of main.scss

Comment: What version of Sass are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, however only for Sass 3.3 and up. Just tried this at [SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/) and it worked with Sass 3.3.4.

In the 3.2 versions this wasn't supported, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

You want this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655130/16940

Example:

```
            @at-root 
            {
                [barSize='large']#{&}
                {
                    font-size: 20px;
                }
            }
```