# In Sass, how to reference two parent classes with ampersand to compound with an element?

Tags: sass

Using the method [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655130/420217), it works, but not for two parent classes.

For instance:

```
.one, .two {
  @at-root a#{&} {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
a.one, .two {
  color: blue;
}
```

Rather than the intended:

```
a.one, a.two {
  color: blue;
}
```

Is there any way to get the intended result using a similar method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `selector-append()` function instead:

```
.one, .two {
  @at-root #{selector-append(a, &)} {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Using interpolation on the parent selector causes Sass to evaluate it as a string (because that's what interpolation *does*).  This only makes it acceptable to use when you have a single selector.  The selector-append (and all other selector-* functions) will evaluate the selector as a list of selectors, appending your desired item to each selector in the list.

Comment: Very cool, thanks. There are a lot of neat and useful Sass functions that it's hard to know and remember them all, but it's quite powerful the more I learn about it!

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in pure CSS with the `:is()` matching pseudo-class:

```
.one, .two {
  &:is(a) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: This still uses SCSS for the nesting though right?

Comment: Yes, `:is()` is only replacing the Sass `selector-append()` function.

Answer (score -3):

Or you simply switch to stylus:

```
.one,
 .two {
   a& {
   color: blue;
 }
}
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzobQZ)

Comment: I doubt that the OP want to switch frameworks just because of this one issue.