# Check element type inside a class selector

Tags: sass, css-selectors

In Sass, we all use to do things like this:

```
button {
  @extend %button;

  &.previous,
  &.next {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Today, I need the exact opposite: check the element type inside a class selector. Here's my first attempt, which I expected to work:

```
.previous,
.next {
  @extend %button;

  &span {
    opacity: .3;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this outputs selectors like `.previousspan` and `.nextspan`. I tried to use `span&`, or interpolation as I highly suppose it could solve my problem, but I'm stuck.

Any idea?

> Note: I could obviously put this `span` selector outside (and that's what I've done to get it to work), but this is not the point of my question. I'm really searching for the *right* way to do it, thanks.

Comment: Then you're looking for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051712/in-sass-how-to-reference-two-parent-classes-with-ampersand-to-compound-with-an

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! Have you got a way to change the duplicate, to redirect on the right answer?

Answer (score 3):

With the latest versions of Sass, you could implement it like so:

```
.class {
  @at-root {
    div#{&} {
      opacity: .3;
    }
  }
}
```

@at-root, will make sure to nullify the "scope" of the selector, while still giving you access to the ampersand variable.

However it's usually a better idea to not target tag names at all. Sementically speaking.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it'll output `.previous span.previous`, which is not correct. And I agree with you about targeting tag names, I'm overriding some CMS styles, and have no control over HTML structure.

Comment: Won't work either, because there're two class selectors. It'll output `span.previous, .next {}` instead of `span.previous, span.next {}`. Anyway, I discovered that `@at-root` could be used as a block wrapper!