# Sass: Is there a way to have a .date { &input[readonly] }

Tags: css, sass

I know I can do all sorts of wonderful things with & in Sass like

```
.date {

  & input[readonly] {
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

But, I've got input[readonly] being set by Foundation 6 to input[readonly] and this won't override it without !important being added.  Seems like this should be solvable without !important, but you can't do this:

```
.date {

  &input[readonly] {
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

Since you'll just get `.dateinput[readonly]{ ... }`.  Is there a way around this so I can get input[readonly].date? The example below won't do that as & has to be used at the start of compound selectors:

```
.date {

  input[readonly]& {
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
.date {

  input[readonly] & {
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

(note the space)

Although this will also add an space between the parent and the child, which is not what you want. You might need to use `@at-root` alongside this, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268051/sass-combining-parent-using-ampersand-with-base-element).

Comment: The @at-root directive is the answer.  That's awesome!  I spent a lot of time trying to find something like this.  I knew it had to be out there go Sass!!!