# Class styled depending on element (h2/h3) with nested SCSS/ampersand?

Tags: html, css, sass

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious here, I can write the CSS for it but I want to know if there's a way to do it with nested SCSS. If you have styling on a class, is it possible to adjust the style if that class is on a different element. For example an `h2` and then an `h3`. I know you can do it with an additional classes, like...

```
.title-class {
    background-size: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;

    &.another-class {
        background-size: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Which would render as `.title-class.another-class {}`

What I'm after is a base class of `.title-class {}` and the nested style as `h3.title-class {}` - Is it possible?

I thought something like the following (in theory) which obviously doesn't work! I tried using @root but my understanding of that is minimal so I couldn't get that to work.

```
.title-class {
    background-size: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;

    &h3 {
        background-size: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a seperate class and an `extend`

Comment: Yeah I was looking at a few ways to do this, it was more out off curiosity. To be honest it's probably just as easy to write 'standard' CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to target all `h3` elements with a class of `title-class`, *without using the `@root` directive* you would use the following:

```
h3 {
  &.title-class {
    color: blue
  }
}
```

Check out [this already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655130/4624718) if you'd like to use the root directive, although I feel personally it is a bit of an over complication in this scenario.

Comment: Yeah some of it seems a bit long winded. To be honest I just wanted to experiment and see how many different ways it could be achieved, if it could at all. Maybe a more 'standard' CSS approach is better suited than nesting stuff for the sake of it and is a lot more readable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've decided just to target it using `h3.title-class {}`. I tried using `@at-root h3#{&}` but it wouldn't work. I think the problem is I have a few alternative `.title-class` ...so the parent is actually setup something like `.title-class-1, .title-class-2, .title-class-3 {}`. I think the multiple class separated by a comma cause the problem?

Comment: To avoid creating multiple rules like that, you may want to check out the [attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110337/4624718). You can match any class that has the word `title-class` in it.