# Sass nested selector using ampersand with different tags

Tags: sass, css-selectors

Is there a way using sass to specify style depending on the `tag` when nesting with multiple class selectors ? For example when you have a generic class selector and need to style it differently when it's a `span` or an `a`. Something like this (that doesn't work):

```
.foo > .bar > .item {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;

    &span {
        color: blue;
    }
    &a {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

It works with classes but for tags I can't find a way. Too bad that there is a css selector `:not()` but no `:is()`, that would have worked.

Comment: Here is the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268051/sass-combining-parent-using-ampersand-with-type-selectors

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can get much closer than this:

```css
.foo > .bar > {
  & .item {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  & span.item {
    color: blue;
  }
  & a.item {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/gqbqzX

And here's a snippet with the compiled CSS.

```css
.foo > .bar > .item {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.foo > .bar > span.item {
  color: blue;
}
.foo > .bar > a.item {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main class="foo">
  <section class="bar">
    <div class="item">A div item </div>
    <span class="item"> A span item</span>
    <a class="item"> An a item</a>
  </section>
</main>
```