# How to make h1, h2, h3 versions for a class with scss?

Tags: sass

I want to define a class and write different styles for its h1, h2, h3 versions:

```scss
.title {
  color: red;
    
  &h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
    
  &h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

I expect the CSS output like this:

```css
.title { 
  color: red; 
}
h1.title { 
  font-size: 18px; 
}
h2.title { 
  font-size: 16px; 
}
```

This is the CSS output I actually get:

```css
.title {
  color: red;
}
.titleh1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.titleh2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Those headlines should also contain the class `.title`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268051/sass-combining-parent-using-ampersand-with-type-selectors

Comment: _"All class must be in .title class"_ - That statement makes no sense, you are misusing CSS' terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using this QA as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268051/sass-combining-parent-using-ampersand-with-type-selectors), you'll need to use `@at-root` and a placeholder:

```
.title {
  color: red;

    @at-root {
        h1#{&} {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        
        h2#{&} {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me this output:

```css
.title {
  color: red;
}
h1.title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h2.title {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```